# What boundary/initial values should one take for running the couplings in the Standard Model?

Tags: standard-model, renormalization

(This is a very naive question!)

I am trying to run the Standard Model(SM) couplings at 2-Loop, which includes three gauge couplings, Yukawa couplings, and Higgs quartic coupling.

This requires me to provide the boundary conditions to numerically solve the renormalisation group equations on Mathematica.

However, I searched several papers, and I am confused about what initial values should I take? As different papers take different values.

As far as I understand, the standard procedure is to provide the initial value at the mass of the Z boson, which is 91.1876 GeV. But I don't know what values for SM couplings I should put there.

I would be very thankful if someone could list the standard initial values here or provide references.

Comment: Suggestion to the post (v1): Replace the words _boundary/initial value_ with the words _choice of [renormalization scheme](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/renormalization+scheme)._